# Difference between calling a sproc vs. SQL Query from PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, stored-procedures

All:

I am creating a web service using PHP and a stored procedure in mySQL. I'm having a problem getting the sproc CALL to work, while a standard INSERT INTO query works well. Can anyone help with what I am doing wrong? The PHP routine works perfectly if I uncomment the line with the INSERT query and comment out the line with the sproc CALL...thanks

```
 $stmt = $this->db->prepare("call Game.addUser(?,?,?,?)");
 //$stmt = $this->db->prepare('INSERT INTO Game.activeUsers (playerName, email, zip,     `password`) VALUES(?,?,?,?);');
 $stmt->bind_param("ssss", $playerName, $email, $zip, $pw);
 $stmt->execute();
```

Thank you!

Comment: What error message do you get?

Answer (score 0):

looks like you have a parameter missmatch:

in prepare you have 4 placeholders, while below in bind_param you have 5

Comment: No, there are 4. "ssss" is used to state they are of the string type.